# terraform databricks_job not starting every time when the job name is same

Tags: terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

terraform is not running databricks_job.

If i delete the job and run terraform, it is creating a job/starting. Is it because of same Job name? we wanted to trigger this job from Airflow, so we wanted to keep the job name static.

Also, the `terraform apply` doesn't show the log for creating job.

**Update:** The reason for using existing cluster is because , we wanted to use the same cluster for multiple spark jobs in sequence.

**sample code:**

```
resource "databricks_job" "db_job" {
  name           = "Sample Job"
  always_running = true

  existing_cluster_id = databricks_cluster.db_cluster.id

  library {
    jar = "dbfs:${local.dbfs_jar_file_path}"
  }

  spark_jar_task {
    main_class_name = "x.x.x.SomeApp"
    parameters = [
      "-Dconfig.file=/dbfs/config.conf"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Job names aren't unique. You may have hundreds of jobs with the same name. Also, Airflow operator doesn't use job name, but the job ID (because name isn't unique)

Comment: @AlexOtt: i understand your point from Airflow about job id, but the real issue was we need to force replace terraform resources, otherwise this is simply not running the job again. Terraform apply shows update job, but nothing happens

Comment: if you have existing job not created by Terraform, then you need to import it into a terraform state as described in docs: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/job#import.  Otherwise Terraform will create a new resource